# Flat Array vs nested Array in React are treated differently

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have noticed that I can pass to React a set of nested arrays and it will render the items properly, but when I go this way, it will not complain of missing `key`s on my elements.

```
const stuff = 'a,b,c';

// Nested Array
// React is fine with it and automatically assigns keys
// Sample data: [[a, <br />], [b, <br />], [c, <br />]]
const Foo = () => <div>{stuff.split(',').map(itm => [itm, <br />])}</div>;

// Flat Array
// React warns me that I should assign a key to each element in array
// Sample data: [a, <br />, b, <br />, c, <br />]
const Bar = () => <div>{stuff.split(',').map(itm => [itm, <br />]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])}</div>;
```

Sample pen:

https://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/NppLPR

Why does it happens? I can't find any reference to "nested arrays" support in React, neither on "auto assigned keys".

Comment: For Arrays of children, use [keyed fragments](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html). The docs acknowledge it's not possible to add a `key` attribute to a native Array and offers the `'react-addons-create-fragment'` package in order to handle them.

Answer (score 4):

You'll notice that even though a warning is printed to the console, React still shows both `Foo` and `Bar` in your HTML being generated. React uses unique keys for reconciliations whilst trying to boost rendering performance. You can read more about this on the [React reconciliation recursing on children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children) page. Not providing keys means React cannot be as performant as it has been designed to be.

With regards to your question as to why a warning is not output to the console for nested arrays, we have to dive into the source code:

The function which generates the warning is called `validateExplicitKey`, and lives in the `ReactElementValidator.js` module.

This function is used in the `validateChildKeys` in the same module - looking into the source code gives the following, as of React 15.4.2:

```
function validateChildKeys(node, parentType) {
  if (typeof node !== 'object') {
    return;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {                     // 1.
    for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      var child = node[i];                       // 2.
      if (ReactElement.isValidElement(child)) {  // 3.
        validateExplicitKey(child, parentType);
      }
    }
  } else if (ReactElement.isValidElement(node)) {
    // This element was passed in a valid location.
    if (node._store) {
      node._store.validated = true;
    }
  } else if (node) {
    var iteratorFn = getIteratorFn(node);
    // Entry iterators provide implicit keys.
    if (iteratorFn) {
      if (iteratorFn !== node.entries) {
        var iterator = iteratorFn.call(node);
        var step;
        while (!(step = iterator.next()).done) {
          if (ReactElement.isValidElement(step.value)) {
            validateExplicitKey(step.value, parentType);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. An array of arrays will enter the first code block
2. the `child` will be set to `child = ["b", Object]` (where 'Object' is react's virtual dom representation for the `br` node we created via JSX)
3. the array will be run through the function `ReactElement.isValidElement`:

   ```
   ReactElement.isValidElement = function (object) {
     return typeof object === 'object' && object !== null && object.$$typeof === REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE;
   };
   ```

with `REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE` being set as:

```
var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol['for'] && Symbol['for']('react.element') || 0xeac7;
```

The array is an object, and is not `null`, but it's `$$typeof` property hasn't been set here, so the check fails.

`$$typeof` hasn't been set because React only adds this property to elements it creates to identify whether something is a React Element or not. This includes native HTML elements, and not data types.

Hence the `ReactElement.isValidElement` check fails, and the warning is never shown.

Comment: By my understanding, yes! The function `traverseAllChildrenImpl` from `react-dom` knows how to traverse children in a multidimensional array (it recursively calls itself to build the children nodes), but the `validateExplicitKey` function doesn't do this

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing recently!

From what I've understood in ReactJS's official docs about [how the `key`s work](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), I would expect to get the same warning with the **nested** array of data, just like the one with the **flat** array of data, since in both cases there are no key attributes set.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys **should be given to the elements inside the array** to give the elements a stable identity.

I actually filled in a [bug report (issue) in the ReactJS official GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9168), describing the same case you pointed out, but simplified (without the fancy `.map()` and `.reduce()` thingies).

It looks like a **bug** to me.

PS: I will update my answer as soon as the React team responds to me.